# Why is the KNN implementation in sklearn slower when I use a smaller float?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I'm using KNN search in my application. Big arrays would consume a lot of memory and I'm trying to reduce the size of the array.

It's too hard for me to reduce the number of dimensions without affecting the result. So I look to reduce the the size by using a smaller `dtype`:

```
In [46]: features = np.random.random((500000, 128)).astype('float32')

In [47]: smaller = features.astype('float16')

In [48]: nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=20, algorithm='brute', metric='l2').fit(f
    ...: eatures)

In [49]: smaller_nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=20, algorithm='brute', metric='l2
    ...: ').fit(smaller)

In [50]: %timeit nbrs.kneighbors(features[3:4])
10 loops, best of 3: 61.7 ms per loop

In [51]: %timeit smaller_nbrs.kneighbors(smaller[3:4])
1 loop, best of 3: 526 ms per loop
```

As you can see, switching to `float16` makes the `kneighbors` call about 10 times slower.

Why is this the case? Is there anything I can do to make it run as fast as when using `float32`?

Comment: As a stab in the dark, NearestNeighbors expects float32, so it's converting to float32. How does it scale with the size of your inputs?

Comment: @aryamccarthy is right. By the way the kNN is a lazy loader, because of that you should try to reduce the number of samples and/or the length of the feature vector to improve the prediction time.

Comment: @DariusMorawiec No, he's wrong. No conversion to float32 happens, it's just that `numpy.einsum` somehow works faster with float32 than with float16.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why 32b float works faster than 16b float is that 32b floats are natively supported by most of the modern CPUs whereas 16b float may require some special handling (e.g. converting to float32). Thusly, while you save the RAM you spend significantly more on computation.
This can be alleviated when proper CPU instructions are used, which might not be the case here (Intel introduced special half-precision opcodes in 2012; [see](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-benefits-of-half-precision-floats)). The caveat is that you can achieve any noticeable speed-up only once your array is larger than 256K (which obviously is your case) but the improvement is between 20 and 40% which can easily be lost via non-optimal traversal of the array (cache misses).

Also, another factor to take into account is the memory data alignment that typically works much better with a full word (for many of the CPUs: 32b or 64b). Plenty of details on the impact of memory alignment and cache usage you can find in [Scott Myers' presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDIkqP4JbkE).